# How to get the address of a file?

Tags: c, file

I want to know the address of a file.

I can open a file using `fopen()`, and then I can use the file pointer to read its contents. Is it possible to get the contents of the file by address? I know that it's reading from a stream instead of a file, but even knowing what the starting address of the stream is would be helpful.

I saw the `FILE` structure, and noticed that there was one `base` pointer contained in it. I have read its value but it is `0`.

What am I doing wrong? Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: Files do not have addresses. You can seek to a specific _position_ in a file though, see the `fseek` function.

Comment: Which address? Its address on disk? The address of the buffer that the runtime system is using to cache data is probably not very helpful. Or do you mean where is the current file pointer after a read (which ftell will give you)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi  Tom Tanne,Thanks for your reply yes my aim is to get the address of the file at run time,it may be a cached address but I want that.ftell is giving the no byte we forward but it respect to the starting,but what is the starting as it showing 0 when i use ftell at starting .

Comment: Hey guys, I got a shiny new bike and I'd like to do the washing-up with it! Is it possible?

Comment: You are not nice .. ;-) @H2CO3

Answer (score 3):

Things in memory (RAM) have addresses which can be read and written to. A file on disk does not have an address. You can only read the file into memory, and then go through it's contents.

Or you can use `fseek` in the streams API to seek to a particular position in a file, and start reading it in memory from there on, or whatever.

To open and read a file in C you can do something like this:

```
/* fread example: read a complete file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
  FILE * pFile;
  long lSize;
  char * buffer;
  size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
  if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

  // obtain file size:
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

  // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
  buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
  if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
  if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

  /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

  // terminate
  fclose (pFile);
  free (buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `mmap` to "load" the file in the memory and access it through it. Note that `mmap` does not allocate memory for the file right away but as you access it.

Comment: @Tony The Lion:Thanks for your answer,can I able to get the address after when it is loaded into memory(as you told:You can only read the file into memory)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You can definitely get an address of a variable (ie `std::string` for example) in memory, but what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to get the address of the file when it is in memory then wnat to access all the bytes upto end of that file,I do not know it is possible or not but I want to know this concepts,Kindly tell me something.I can tell I just opened a file then I want to know the base address then using that I want to read all upto end of the file.

Comment: @pradipta you just use `fopen` and then `fread` or any of it's variants. This will give you full access to the file and it's contents

Answer (score 1):

Memory mapped files can make this happen, but they are an OS-specific feature (supported by most systems) and not provided by the Standard library.