# How to achive strings command output and during execution of same binary file on Linux

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a program and I want to achieve the output for each of the strings like the output i received from the 'strings command`

```
int my_print(char *fmt, ...)
{
printf("%p\n",fmt);
}

int main()
{
my_print("Hello1 [%d]\n", 1);
my_print("Hello2 [%d]\n", 2);
my_print("Hello [%d]\n", 3);
my_print("Hello3 [%d]\n", 4);
```

and it gave me output

```
0x4006ac
0x4006b9
0x4006c6
0x4006d2
```

Now i executed strings command "strings -t x a.out"
and it gave me output

```
200 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    2c1 __gmon_start__
    2d0 libc.so.6
    2da printf
    2e1 __libc_start_main
    2f3 GLIBC_2.2.5
    639 l$ L
    63e t$(L
    643 |$0H
    6ac Hello1 [%d]
    6b9 Hello2 [%d]
    6c6 Hello [%d]
    6d2 Hello3 [%d]
```

I know that strings gave me offset in a binary file a.out for the strings but i want to know is it possible to print that starting address from where the offset began.
For example Hello1 `strings command` output says "6ac Hello1 [%d]" where as the output of program says 0x4006ac, I want my program should print the mask value and can say that 6ac is the output that i should expect from strings command.

Comment: There is no relation between a strings (or anything else) location in the executable file and the virtual address it is loaded into during execution. Not on normal desktop operating systems. If you want to know how an executable file looks like then read more about [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Comment: I tried not the same but some how related to this question,but haven't got the perfect solution. you can check it. > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512485/how-to-get-the-address-of-a-file I know there is some way to get the starting address of the file which is stored in the memory.I am searching it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If that is C, then you are using variable argument incorrectly.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

int my_print(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list vl ;
    va_start( vl, fmt ) ;
    vprintf(fmt, vl);
}

int main()
{
    my_print("Hello1 [%d]\n", 1);
    my_print("Hello2 [%d]\n", 2);
    my_print("Hello [%d]\n", 3);
    my_print("Hello3 [%d]\n", 4);
}
```

See [details](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) in the C Book.

What you did was as follows. You define a function with a variable number of arguments, but you never use these arguments. Instead, you pass it as a pointer to string and treat it as an argument to printf, using something completely different as a format. printf, correctly, prints the pointer of the string that you passed (that was intended as a format...).

Comment: #include <stdarg.h> contains definitions of above functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i'm looking for the address to be printed as it was printed by 'strings' command.

Comment: Sorry, your code was confusing -- it really looked like you tried to achieve something else.